# Prove that the space P is a Hilbert Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Prove that the space P of all entire functions of the form
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\varphi(t) e^{-izt} dt,$$
is a Hilbert Space, where $\varphi\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. The inner product of two functions f and g in P is defined to
$$(f,g)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t) g^*(t) dt$$
Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: $f$ is the fourier transform of $\phi$ on the torus $\mathbb T$. $\mathcal F: L^2 \to L^2$ is an isometric isomorphism. (i.e. $f\in L^2 \quad \forall \phi\in L^2$ wich suffices for you since $L^2$ is a hilbert space).

Comment: @AlexR Your comment is concise and your point is perfectly valid here, why not write it up as an answer? :)

Comment: @Phonon It uses a nontrivial result wich I am unsure the OP is aware of and is allowed to use.

Comment: @AlexR fair enough, let's see if he will comment on this matter.

Comment: @Phonon I have come up to your suggestion, since I think it is an answer, though maybe not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Mark further helpful links regarding $L^2$ spaces and Hilbert space axioms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that at first your definition is only suitable for $\phi\in L^1(\mathbb T) \cap L^2(\mathbb T)$, but can be continuously extended to $\phi\in L^2(\mathbb T)$.
The Operator taking $\phi$ to $f$ is precisely the fourier transform $\mathcal F$. It is a fundamental result of complex analysis that $\mathcal F: L^2(\mathbb T) \to L^2(\mathbb T)$ is an isometric isomorphism. All you need though is that it is an isomorphism, since this guarantees that $P = L^2(\mathbb T)$, wich is a hilbert space.

Comment: Short and concise. +1